# How to parse links on a page (Golang)

Tags: go, parsing

how to use golang to parse the links on the page, and then to parse the rest of the data I need from these links

The code below parses the links on the page, but I can't figure out how to make it further parse what I need from these links

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/gocolly/colly"
)

type Pars struct {
    link  string
    //price string
    //title string
}

func main() {
    scrapURL := "https://www.dba.dk/mobil-og-telefoni/mobiltelefoner-og-tilbehoer/iphone/model-12/"
    c := colly.NewCollector(
        colly.AllowedDomains("www.dba.dk"),
    )
    var parse []string
    c.OnHTML(".dbaListing", func(h *colly.HTMLElement) {
        parse = append(parse, h.Text)
    })
    c.Visit(scrapURL)
    pars := Pars{}
    pars.link = parse[0]

    fmt.Println(pars)

}
```

Comment: `go` usually has good parsing support out of the box - do check out the tags that your pkg provides - adding these to your custom struct and  un-marshaling should give you the desired results